# SCons does not seem to install (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, installation, scons, setup.py

I have been trying for hours to install SCons on my Windows 8.1 machine and simply cannot. I honestly have no idea whatsoever what I'm doing wrong, or really what I'm doing in general. Here is the step by step process of what I have done

1: installed Python 3.7 from [www.python.org](https://www.python.org) I used the python-3.7.3-amd64.exe to install it, it seems to have worked (I have never used python before so if anything is off I wouldn't realize it). When I use the command console and input 'python --version' it outputs 'Python 3.7.3'

2: I downloaded scons-3.0.5.zip from [www.scons.org](https://www.scons.org) I followed the website's [instructions](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch01s03.html) as best I could. I used 7zip to extract it's contents into a new file called 'scons-3.0.5' located at C:\ It's complete path, therefore, is C:\scons-3.0.5

3: I ran Python 3.7 as an admin. I inputted '# cd scons-3.0.5' just as the scons website [says to do](https://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user/ch01s03.html). It outputted nothing, and I noticed that the new line started with '...' instead of '>>>', I have no previous experience with Python so I don't know if that's good or bad. I then continued to follow the instructions by inputting '# python setup.py install', it outputted nothing, and once more the new line started with '...'. I hoped that was all I needed to do but in the command console I inputted 'scons --version' (I read somewhere this can be done to check if it is installed), it outputs "'scons' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.". This, combined with the fact that seemingly nothing is different, leads me to believe it has not been installed.

4: I tried to do something a bit different. I noticed that the zipped file I downloaded from the scons website contained 2 files in it, 1 being scons-3.0.5, the other being pywin32-master.zip, I had both of these in the file C:\scons-3.0.5 I decided to delete that file, and in its same location place the scons-3.0.5 file. Now instead of C:\scons-3.0.5 including scons-3.0.5 and pywin32-master.zip it contained just the contents of the scons-3.0.5 file that was in it before (if that makes sense, I might clean it up in the morning and make it easier to read). I once more did step 3, and the results were no different.

I have no idea what I'm doing, I have no prior experience with Python or the command console, I just want to set up scons and never use Python again. Does anyone know how I can fix this? I have googled for hours but it seems as if I'm the only one who's having this issue.

The contents of the zipped file from scons website:
[image: scons-3.0.5.zip]

contents of the scons-3.0.5 file in the zipped file
[image: scons-3.0.5.zip\scons-3.0.5]

I doubt the images will help but I have included them just in case if they seem off

edit: I did know what installing via Pip was, but I googled it and it worked just fine! Thanks to Alexander Lopatin and bdbaddog for the help

Comment: Before downloading always try command 'python -m pip install scons' It may save you from later troubles.

Comment: I second that, please try `pip` first...as the webpage you linked in your questions also properly suggests: "If a pre-built SCons package is not available for your system, **and installing using pip is not suitable**, then you can still easily build and install SCons using the native Python distutils package."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're mistake is in step 3.

> I ran Python 3.7 as an admin. I inputted '# cd scons-3.0.5'

The website says:

> # cd scons-3.0.5
>
> # python setup.py install

Notice this is

1. cd into the unzipped directory
2. THEN run `python setup.py install`

Instead you've run python, then typed a shell command into python. Which is why you had issues.

**Note: On windows you shouldn't need to run as admin to install SCons.**

Although as @dirkbaechle said. Pip is the preferred method to install python.

```
python -mpip install scons
```

But if you'd rather follow the instructions.  Just bring up a windows command shell, or powershell if you like, cd into the unzipped directory, and run python setup.py install

BTW. There's an IRC channel and a users mailing list for SCons support.

https://scons.org/contact.html